# Changing the name of a Quartz.NET job or trigger before scheduling

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

This is probably a simple question, but I am pretty new to using Quartz.NET, but how do you change the name of a job or trigger before scheduling?  I am basically making a template job in a support class, and then using it in my main program that handles the scheduling.

Since I need unique names for each job/trigger, I was basically going to take the template job's name like "SomeJob" to "SomeJob01" when I copy it in to the main program for scheduling.

This appears like it would be simple, but all I find when i search is people saying that you can't change job details after they have been scheduled, where this one is I am changing the name so that I CAN schedule them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Quartz, a job is separate from its scheduling trigger. You can add the same job with multiple triggers.

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are doing with the job, but to add it to Quartz, you can do:

```
private const string DEFAULT_GROUP = "MyDefaultGroup";

Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeHourlyTrigger();

JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("YourUniqueJobName", DEFAULT_GROUP, typeof(YourJobClass));

// now add the job to Quartz
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

In this manner you can either add a new job with a unique name and assign a new trigger to it, or you could assign a new trigger to an existing job.

But generally speaking, to modify something in Quartz, you have to remove it, change your object, and then re-add it.

Here is an overview of jobs/triggers:
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_2.html

Here is more information on how triggers work:
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_4.html

Here is more information on how jobs work:
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html

Comment: I forgot a bit about the jobs and triggers are different part, but the reason was when I used `scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);` for the same job, it complained that the job already existed.  I ended up using that if `scheduler.CheckExists(jobDetail.Key)` returns false, otherwise use `scheduler.schedulerJob(trigger)` with the `.forJob(jobDetail)` set on it.  I am perplexed why ScheduleJob does not have ANYTHING built in to say that if the job already exists, schedule that trigger to that job's already existing instance, instead of having to check externally like this.

Comment: If you are just looking to change the schedule of a job, you have to unschedule existing trigger for that job like this: `scheduler.UnscheduleJob(TriggerKey);`. If you want to add a trigger to an existing job, you can set the job's name in the trigger and then do `scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);`. One job can have multiple triggers, so if you just add a new trigger, the job will end up with 2 triggers. You should unschedule first, and then add a trigger with a new schedule.

Comment: @Xantham Since 2.0 you can actually replace an existing job by setting the replace attribute. E.g. `scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger, true);` So you don't need to call `scheduler.CheckExists`.